DateTimeLocalField returns a ValueError due to formatting issue
From what I can tell the formatting is correct. The traceback states the following:
    ValueError: time data Markup('<input id="start_date" name="start_date" type="datetime-local" value="2024-12-20T09:32">') does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'

The following is the code:
app.py
  class TestDateForm(FlaskForm):
      start_date = DateTimeLocalField('Service Start Date', format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M') #, validators=(validators.DataRequired(),))
          
      submit = SubmitField('Submit')

routes.py
    @app.route('/test_date', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def test_date():
        form = TestDateForm()

        if form.is_submitted():       
            date_string = str(form.start_date)
            date = datetime.strptime(date_string,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M') #also tried :%S') 
            print(date)  # for debugging
            
            flash('The date/time picker works correctly!', 'success')
    
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('test_date.html', title='Test Date Picker', form=form)

If I just run a simple form with <input type='datetime-local> then all the values are returned correctly and I can strptime the time and date as expected.
Any ideas on what I have missed?

The confusion was in what was actually being returned. Further testing showed my result in a format of 2024-12-20 13:45:00.
Instead of using the following code in routes.py:
    if form.is_submitted():   

        date_string = str(form.start_date)
        date = datetime.strptime(date_string,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M') #also tried :%S') 
        print(date)  # for debugging
        
        flash('The date/time picker works correctly!', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('index'))

I changed it to this:
    if form.is_submitted():
   
        date_string = str(form.start_date.data)
        date = datetime.strptime(date_string,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print(date)  # for debugging
            
        flash('The date/time picker works correctly!', 'success')
    
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

The class TestDateForm remained the same, and if you change that format it doesn't work either.
    class TestDateForm(FlaskForm):
        start_date = DateTimeLocalField('Service Start Date', format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')

Reading the data from the field helped. All the reference material I came across never mentioned this, when using the DateTimeLocalField. I should have tried this at the beginning.
